# proper way of checking $_GET variable

Tags: php, if-statement

I must check in PHP that the `$_GET` variable is set, and also an Integer.

Which of these two methods should I consider safe to use for this purpose?

#### Method 1:

```
$debtor_id = intval($_GET['id']);
if ($debtor_id > 0){
    //everything is good continue.
}else{
    header("location: error404.php");
}
```

#### Method 2

```
if (isset($_GET['id'])){
    $debtor_id = intval($_GET['id']);
    //everything is good continue.
}else{
    header("location: error404.php");
}
```

Please feel free to advise me of any different ways to do it.

Comment: there are a hundred different ways. `is_int()` would be a logical choice

Comment: Use method 2. Every $_GET[] at first must exist, what we controled by isset, after that process.

Answer (score 2):

Method 3: use [one of PHP's built-in filter functions](http://php.net/manual/en/function.filter-input.php).

```
$debtor_id = filter_input(INPUT_GET, 'id', FILTER_VALIDATE_INT);

if (!$debtor_id) {
    header('location: error404.php');
    exit;
}
// everything is good continue.
```

With that filter function,

- if `$_GET['id']` isn't set, `$debtor_id` will be set to `null`
- if `$_GET['id']` is set and isn't an int, `$debtor_id` will be set to `false`
- if `$_GET['id']` is set and is an int, `$debtor_id` will be set to that int

`null`, `false`, and `0` will all evalute to `false` in your if condition. (In your method 1 you check that it's greater than zero, so I assume that's also a condition.)

Answer (score 0):

Use Method 2 with isset function. 
Why ?

Because in the method 1, you don't check if the variable $_GET['id] exists, which means that inval($_GET['id']) will return an error because your parameter doesn't exist.
That's the main goal of the isset function, which is by the way, the traditionnal way in PHP to deal with GET values.